# Multiple-monitor display doesn't work after update to 13.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 13.10

I upgraded from 12.04 to 13.10, and after that, my secondary monitor doesn't work anymore.

A little more info:

```
$ xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024       0.0* 
   1024x768        0.0  
   800x600         0.0  
   640x480         0.0  

$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti] (rev a1)

$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF114 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f4000000-f5ffffff memory:e8000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f3ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f6000000-f607ffff
```

Even at login screen, it doesn't detect it at all.

So, anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this issue searching for another display-related problem on this upgrade. here are the steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-settings-331
```

And then restart the computer

Comment: The PPA says that you shouldn't install packages from it separately. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and sort of panicked but all I had to do was go to control panel, click on Adjust screen resolution under Appearance and Personalization.

Then adjust monitor 1, monitor 2 and so on accordingly!

Hope this helps

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work, the other display wasn't even there.

Comment: Ok, I just searched a solution for another display-related problem: mouse flickering. Reinstalled the ppa repository and installed nvidia 331 drivers. That solved the multiple-monitor issue as well