# how do I get defaults for 13.10

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, 13.10

I just upgraded my system to 13.10 and I may have made a mistake. At one stage it asked me about gnome something and if I wanted the defaults or to keep what I had. I may have mistakenly chosen to keep what I had.

The immediate problem I have (which may or may not be connected to the above) is that the system is getting confused with my 2 monitors. At the stage of login it has them backwards - the right one on the left and the left on the right. I can tell this by moving the cursor from one screen to the other - it goes off the right edge of the right screen and lands on the left edge of the left screen.

When the system comes up I can see that it is still wrong because the left one is 1920x1080 and the right is 1680x1050 and the left image comes over to 1680 instead of 1920. If I move the cursor to the right edge suddenly it straightens itself out.

Two questions: 1) if I can somehow ask for the default values of the gnome - if that is a possible problem. 2) if I can set up proper values for the screen positions at boot time?

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 2):

You are probably talking about `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` which has nothing to do with monitors as far as I know.

You should be able to find `/etc/gnome/defaults.list.dpkg-old` or `/etc/gnome/defaults.list.dpkg-new` depending on which file you choose to install during upgrade.

You can also search for the package that contains the particular file:

```
$ dpkg  --search /etc/gnome/defaults.list
desktop-file-utils: /etc/gnome/defaults.list
```

Reinstalling should also work:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall desktop-file-utils
```

[How can I restore configuration files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files)

As always, it's important that you know the exact error message. The system keeps logs for you: [Can I look at the upgrade log after a distribution upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130969/can-i-look-at-the-upgrade-log-after-a-distribution-upgrade)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I looked at the defaults and I too can see no connection to the monitors. I also looked at the log files and since I don't remember what the error was, the log files are impossibly big to try and guess. Is there a reasonably easy way to try to do the upgrade all over again?

Comment: I found an answer that works: http://askubuntu.com/questions/355907/multiple-monitor-display-doesnt-work-after-update-to-13-10?rq=1  Perhaps I needed an update on my nvidia? Whatever the reason, it did the trick.

Comment: I had this issue while doing a dist-upgrade and accidentally pressed enter to keep the old version.  Luckily the new version was in `/etc/gnome/defaults.list.dpkg-dist`